# What am I doing wrong in my powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

Ok here is the thing. I tried to make a PowerShell script to create some folders and to change a couple of strings in a .txt file.

But as you can guess it is not working. See my configuration below:

```
Start-Transcript
[string]$CustomerName = Read-host "Enter the company name of the customer (e.g. Companyname)"
write-host ""
[string]$Hostname = Read-host "Enter the FQDN of the customers machine (e.g. HV00.domain.local)"
write-host ""
[string]$Logon = Read-host "Enter te logon credentials of the customers machine (e.g. domain\user)"
write-host ""
[string]$Password = Read-host "Enter the password of the customers machine"
write-host ""

cd C:\Monitor\Logs
mkdir .\$CustomerName
cd C:\Monitor\Logs\$CustomerName
mkdir .\$Hostname
cd $Home

cd C:\Monitor\Scripts\CustomScript
mkdir .\$CustomerName
cd $Home

$InputFile = "C:\Monitor\Scripts\BaseScript\BaseScript.txt"
$OutputFile = "C:\Monitor\Scripts\CustomScript\$CustomerName\$CustomerName.txt"
```

This is not working

```
(Get-Content $InputFile) | ForEach-Object { $_ 
-replace "hostname", "$Hostname" `
-replace "username@domainname", "$Logon" `
-replace "password", "$Password" } `
-replace "C:\Monitor\Logs\customername\hostname\", "C:\Monitor\Logs\$Customername\$Hostname\" 
} | Set-Content $OutputFile
```

This is working, but I can only replace one string with it

```
(Get-Content $InputFile) -replace "hostname", "$Hostname" > $OutputFile
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Break down what isn't working into their own parts.  Please indicate what part of "what isn't working" works and what doesn't work.  Basic debugging 101.

Answer (score 0):

It would be handy if you would paste the error you're getting as well. But
you have one closing curly bracket too much in your for-loop's code, which is probably it:

```
-replace "password", "$Password" } `  <=== this one
```

btw, you can shorten the amount of subfolder creation code by creating the whole tree at once, which PowerShell can handle perfectly

```
mkdir c:\foo\bar\this\will\all\be\created\in\one\statement
```